# Installing grab, site scraping library

Tags: python, dependencies

I was trying to find libraries that would help me for auto form filling . Someone suggested me  Grab(a site scraping library) from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/grab/0.4.8 . I uncompressed tar.gz and then tried the following ,

```
python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 1, in <module>
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Does anyone know how to install it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is clear and simple.

> ImportError: No module named setuptools

Please check, if you've installed setuptools for python3 or python2.

An example on archlinux, (python => python3), (python2 => python2)

Be careful with that

Please try with "python2 setup.py install"